# Does putting temp files to a ramdisk have any negative impact?

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, windows-explorer, ramdisk

I am planning to dump all temp files into ramdisk to boost performance and reduce writes to main storage, so two temp folders(in system and user folders) will be moved.

What I am concerned about is there might be possibilities this decision will cause the system or apps not to function as intended. What comes to mind for now is some temp files are not meant to be removed on a daily basis, but should be kept for some period of time as they are probably essential for the apps or system to work properly and be deleted when it is the right time.

Maybe for browsing history(cache) it would be safe to do so as it is nothing but bits and bytes of images or texts for faster future preloading whenever visiting the website again.

Any advise is well thanked for..

Comment: SSD's have limited write cycles. If there were a lot of files being created continually, you run the risk of killing the drive. According to this article, https://www.compuram.de/blog/en/the-life-span-of-a-ssd-how-long-does-it-last-and-what-can-be-done-to-take-care/, each cell may get 3,000 writes, though the controller will try to distribute that.

Comment: How much is written to temp files overall, and what impact does it have on system performance? My guess would be that your 'savings' would be less than the measuring noise, so you might invite problems for nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes SSD has limited P/E cycles before it completely is worn out which is the main reason I am in search of reducing the writes. but in my personal experience "temp files" are not in reality "temporary" for variety of cases. I didn't measure the performance gain but my main storage is NVME ssd so I almost cannot notice the difference actually. and at the moment two temp folders have 140MBs of data in total. Have run disk cleanup tool twice but many temp files still remain alive.

Comment: Terror about killing an SSD is mostly misplaced these days. It is OK to consider a recently produced SSD to have a lifetime similar to a mechanical HDD.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be reasonable to move temporary directories to RAMDrive to spare your SSDs as some unix distribution does, but I've experienced some strange issues when I tried (using OSFMount as RAMDrive application).
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio for C/C++ developing and Performance Profiling cannot be used when user's TEMP directory is on RAMDrive. Even if I tried to trick MS by symlinking TEMP folder to a folder on RAMDrive. It works like a charm if TEMP folder is on another disk (not system disk), but always fails when it is on RAMDrive.
NPM installs can also fail on RAMDrive since Node gyp building has some similar problems (I think it is also Visual Studio related).
And lastly TEMP folder on RAMDrive can also prevent some Windows Updates to finish successfully, so under Windows you can save yourself from a lot of time consuming error searching if avoid Windows TEMP folder usage on RAMDrive.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be not to do that. Here is why:

First, temporary files are rarely used for intensive read-write
operations, so are usually not a performance bottleneck.

Second, the Windows memory cache works much like a RAM disk, so for
most operations will be just as efficient. Microsoft has been tuning
it for decades, so it's pretty good.

Third, as you said, some temporary files are far from temporary, so
deleting them on each reboot might cause some applications to lose
context or be unable to recover from crash.

Answer (score 0):

Be very sure what temp files you will move.  Some temp files are in use after an app has been closed.

Moving these to a ram disk and then the RAM disk has an issue could be disastrous to the app(s).

Just be very certain of what you are moving.

Try just deleting the temp files. If you cannot delete them (in use), then do not move them to a RAM disk.

That is just one test.  Also see what app or part of the OS owns the temp files. That is another approach.

Numerous temp folders, e.g. AppData itself is part of the User Profile and can be very disastrous to move. There are some folders/files in AppData Temp which might be moved - some cannot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think this is not technically possible since the relocating the temp files are done folder-wise, meaning you just have two options : move the location all temp files are saved, or just leave it.  and it is practially impossible to know what temp files are created on running pc every day.

Comment: That is why I suggested to be very careful about what files. If you do not know, you could do some significant damage. I have seen that happen

Comment: `%Temp%` [`%LocalAppData%\Temp`] can be safely moved to a different location, just not through the GUI _(`%LocalAppData%` itself should never be moved due to hard links within, with `%Temp%` being one of the rare exceptions for data within it)_

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your suggestion.  Too dangerous, I think, to change without knowing first.

Comment: I know it's an old topic but if I can add my 2 cents: I've used ImDisk RAM drives for years, both at home and at work, with no adverse effect whatsoever, except when I experimented with locating a pagefile in the RAM drive. In that case, and regardless of the file system I used, and the quantity of RAM available, at some point the pagefile would get clogged, possibly because ImDisk's file system driver is a bit old and doesn't release memory with as much finesse as Windows 10+ or Server 2019+ do nowadays. Otherwise, it's working fine, even as I write this comment.